# Integrating SwiftUI iOS Push Notification APN with Rails JSON backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swift, swiftui, apple-push-notifications

I am creating an iOS app that uses swiftUI for the app but it talks to a Rails Backend via HTTP requests to JSON. I would like to be able to send push notifications from the backend to users of the frontend.

I gather this deviceToken on the frontend like so:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
        print("deviceToken", deviceTokenString)
    }
}
```

Which gives me a deviceTokenString that looks something like:

`token = "9cfa2410a3f8326529db2e6e34dbcd3cc6664c7ee3675a08a34bd42429892068"`

I got this from [this blog post](https://nshipster.com/apns-device-tokens/) which references this [stack-overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372815/how-can-i-convert-my-device-token-nsdata-into-an-nsstring/24979958).

I then take that token over to my Rails code which looks like this (I'm trying to use [Apnotic](https://github.com/ostinelli/apnotic) but maybe I should be using something else)

```
module PushNotifier

  class << self

    def push(token)
      notification = Apnotic::Notification.new(token)
      notification.alert = 'Test notification from rails'
      notification.topic = 'me.MyApp'
      response = connection.push(notification)
      puts response
    end 

    def connection
      Apnotic::Connection.new(
        auth_method: :token,
        cert_path: "config/keys/AuthKey.p8",
        key_id: Rails.application.credentials.apple.p8_key_id,
        team_id: Rails.application.credentials.apple.team_id
      )   
    end 
  end 
end
```

but I am getting this:

`#<Apnotic::Response:0x00000001069e1018 @headers={":status"=>"400", "apns-id"=>"272ebadf-9b2f-47f6-8ae0-5746422e7213"}, @body="{\"reason\":\"BadDeviceToken\"}">`

so a `400` with `BadDeviceToken`

I'm not sure if the frontend is providing a bad token or somehow the backend is mangling it.

It could be that my `topic` is wrong?

Could it be that the token I am providing is not in the correct hex format of the `deviceToken` string from the frontend?

I think my p8 key and my credentials and certificates are all handled correctly.

Any advice about what could be going on?

Answer (score -1):

Ok I figured it out. I thought maybe I should post here.

This stack overflow answer gave me the idea:

[What are the possible reasons to get APNs responses BadDeviceToken or Unregistered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42511476/what-are-the-possible-reasons-to-get-apns-responses-baddevicetoken-or-unregister)

I realized that maybe my rails side was trying to send to the "production" server when I should be doing development, at least at the moment. I poked around the Apnotic docs and boom:

I changed this line:

```
Apnotic::Connection.new(
```

to

```
Apnotic::Connection.development(
```

which I don't like that API design, but it fixed the issue.